# -pdf-frame-border is broken [xhtml2pdf]

Tags: xhtml2pdf

I've updated xhtml2pdf 0.0.6, PyPDF2 1.21, and reportlab 3.1.8.

My pdf was fine when i used xhtml2pdf 0.0.5 and reportlab 2.7. Now all of my frame got border. I did remove "-pdf-frame-border" and tried to put "-pdf-frame-border:0" or "-pdf-frame-border:none", but it still display frame broder. Can anyone shed any lights? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just revert ReportLab to 2.7 and it fixed the problem.

Comment: I have downgraded Reportlab - reportlab.Version returns "2.7" - and I have PyPDF2-1.21-py2.7.egg-info, xhtml2pdf-0.0.6-py2.7.egg-info and still getting these stupid borders.  Could you elaborate a bit on what your style blocks look like or if you have different versions of either of the other packages? edit: I removed all "-pdf-frame-border:0" and the borders went away

Answer (score 5):

After a bit of poking around with reportlab.Version == 3.1.8, I was only successful by setting a **white border**.

```
@frame footer_frame {
    -pdf-frame-content: footer_content;
    left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 772pt; height: 20pt;
    border: 0pt solid white;
}
```